# RewriteMap not working, nothing is rewritten (Apache 2.4)

Tags: apache-2.4, mod-rewrite, rewrite, rewritemap

I have a bit of a unique situation: I need to take a subdomain and make it redirect to a random selection of alternate domains, each of which is on a separate server. Think load balancing, except it's technically different from that.

Upon investigating my options, Apache's RewriteMap seemed like the ideal solution, except I can't seem to get it to do anything at all. Here's what I've got so far:

In my configuration file, I've added:

```
RewriteMap map "rnd:/home/mydomain/public_html/servers.txt"
```

This is in the server context, not VirtualHost or Directory. However, I do have "AllowOverride All" set for the public_html directory. And yes, I did remember to restart Apache after saving changes to my config.

Next, the servers.txt file itself:

```
servers domain1.com|domain2.com|domain3.com
```

(It doesn't really matter if these domains are exposed to the user, hence I'm just putting this in public_html for now, but I may move it elsewhere if I can get it working.)

Finally, I have an .htaccess file in public_html which already has several working Rewrite conditions and rules. RewriteEngine is on and all that. But when I add...

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain.domain.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "https://${map:servers}/$1" [P,L]
```

... visiting my subdomain just shows the subdomain itself. I've tried a variety of different flags, but to no avail. At best, if I replace the [P] flag with [R=301] I can get a ERR_INVALID_REDIRECT response from the browser, which tells me the rule is at least being processed. Other than that, I don't even get any errors in Apache's error_log file. I've also made sure no other rules have the [L] flag, which might cause the new rule to be skipped.

As far as I can tell, according to the Apache documentation this is *exactly* the way RewriteMap is supposed to be used, so I'm a little perplexed to say the least. Can anyone tell me what I'm missing here?

Answer (score 0):

> I've also made sure no other rules have the [L] flag

That raises alarm bells. It perhaps implies you've put these directives in the wrong place in your `.htaccess` file. Your "redirect" should go near the top of your `.htaccess` file. (I would expect *most* `RewriteRule` directives to require the `L` flag and at the very least for optimisation.)

mod_rewrite directives naturally chain together - in that the output of the previous is the input of the next and so on. If you've removed the `L` flags from preceding directives and placed your redirect later in the file then your `$1` backreference is not capturing the requested URL, but the rewritten URL from any preceding directives.

You should be able to see the URL that triggers the ERR_INVALID_REDIRECT in the browser by monitoring the network traffic (in the browser tools).

> if I replace the [P] flag with [R=301]

The `P` flag sends the request through mod_proxy (as a reverse proxy - which requires additional config). If you want to *externally redirect* the request then you should use the `R` flag.

Comment: Your explanation of the [L] flag makes sense--apparently I was slightly misunderstanding its function based on the Apache documentation. However, even adding other [L] flags to end rules and moving the RewriteMap rule to the top of `.htaccess` produces the same results.

Also, the [R] flag seems like the right way to go here since the alt domains are external, but it silently errors no matter what I do. Nothing comes up in network tools at all.

Comment: If you are seeing a ERR_INVALID_REDIRECT _browser_ error then you should be able to examine the initial HTTP (redirect) response from your server containing the `Location:` header.

Comment: I'm not able to find one either in my browser tools or server logs, but I believe I discovered what's going on, regardless: the domain is just being skipped, leading the browser to attempt to access the subdirectory as the domain. So instead of https://example.com/sub/file.txt it ends up as https://sub/file.txt which obviously isn't going anywhere. So, the RewriteMap is returning an empty string. *Why* remains a mystery without any errors to examine...